# How can I estimate the execution time of convolution on PXA27x processor?

Tags: c++, intel, timing, cpu-cycles

I am a civil engineering student, so please be gentle :)

I have to give a rough estimate of the timing of an algorithm working on an Intel PXA271 processor, with XScale architecture. Basically, my "algorithm" does a filtering of the signal acquired in real time, and sends the results via wireless. Considering four filters of N = 2788 taps each (f1, f2, f3, and f4), for each new sample of collected data, my algorithm refreshes the window of incoming signal x, performs the convolution with all the filters, and returns y1, y2, y3, and y4 as a result:

```
y1 = y2 = y3 = y4 = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   y1 += f1[i]*x[i];
   y2 += f2[i]*x[i];
   y3 += f3[i]*x[i];
   y4 += f4[i]*x[i];
}
```

Now, I would like to estimate how long the processor takes to perform this part of code. I am following the [Optimization guide](http://www.penguin.cz/~utx/zaurus/datasheets/CPU/28000402.pdf) related to the PXA27x processor family, which "explains" what pipelines are (ok, I also tried to study pipelines on other references in the last days), and shows an example of optimization considering a code similar to mine (page 4-22), and telling how to avoid stalls. From this example, it seems that each multiply-accumulate operation takes only one cycle (except for additional cycles due to stalls) before optimization. However, after optimization, (§4.4.2.1) the reference says that only 0.625 cycles per tap are necessary. So, in my example, can I say that, after optimizing the instructions in some way, the total number of cycles would be less than 4*2788? Therefore, working at 13 MHz, the total time would be less than (4*2788)/(13*10^6) = 8.6e-4 sec?

I also tried to do the count "manually", using the instruction latencies of §4.8 of the [Optimization guide](http://www.penguin.cz/~utx/zaurus/datasheets/CPU/28000402.pdf). In this case, without any optimization, looking at Table 4-6, I referred to 4 cycles per instructions as the worst case for MLA. So, the total number of cycles would be 4*4*2788. Is it correct? Why in the first case, before optimization the number of cycles for the MLA was 1? Can somebody explain me what does "Rs Value" and "S-Bit Value" (referring to Table 4-6) mean in simple language? Is it referred to the type of data I want to handle?

I'm sorry if I wrote something nonsense, and thank you if you have the patience to explain or give me some simple reference to understand.

Comment: I think you can have a look at `std::chrono` [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: You can also disassemble your code and based on number of instructions you can derive the number of cycles of execution of your algorithm, [disassembler](https://godbolt.org/), this is a good tool to disassemble your code

Comment: @VasanthAlagiriswamy thanks for your advices! I used the dissembler to obtain the assembly of my code, but then, do I have to derive the number of cycles manually? If yes, the problem is that I don't know how many cycles to account for multiply-accumulate! I tried to study the optimization guide in the main post, but it's not clear to me